# How to configure retention in Prometheus and Grafana with bitnami helm charts

Tags: grafana, bitnami, prometheus-operator

How is retention of data handled in Grafana and Prometheus?

I have installed Grafana and Prometheus in a kubernetes cluster using bitnami helm charts.
Is there a way to handle retention policy or will I just run out of space at some time?

Comment: Hi @Michael. Have you tried this `--set prometheus.retention` parameter during installation? It should help. See the [referance](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/kube-prometheus/#prometheus-parameters). Or define it in `values.yaml` file, under *server* block in this way  e.g. 
`server.retention: 5d`

Comment: Not sure why I missed that....thanks